# Flipping the limits in Lebesgue Integration

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I'm solving a problem in Real Analysis, namely, to prove:

> If $f$ is integrable, then $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)dt$ is uniformly continuous

In trying to solve this, I desperately wanted to use the calculus trick that $$\int_a^b f(x)dx = - \int_b^a f(x)dx$$
Under the assumption that this works, my proof came out nicely. My question is, is this a legal move in Lebesgue integration?

What I've gathered looking at the Riemann proof of this integration flipping is that we have the identity:

> $$\int_a^b f + \int_b^c f = \int_a^c f$$

Which is certainly true in the Lebesgue case. Letting $c =a$ we get the desired flip, since $\int^c_c f =0$. This is, again, true in the Lebesgue case since $[c,c]$ has measure zero.

Have I missed something important here? I have not seen this used in any of the textbooks I'm using and I am sort of teaching myself the subject, so a verification would be appreciated.

Comment: Even in Riemann integration, one has to declare by definition that $\int_a^af:=0$, and for $a<b$, $\int_b^af:=-\int_a^bf$ (that "identity" you quote is first proven for $a<b<c$, and then by extending the definition of notation, it is proved for all $a,b,c$). So, if you want to use such a notation in the Lebesgue setting, then one has to declare that for $a\leq b$, $\int_a^bf:=\int_{[a,b]}f\,dm$ and $\int_b^af:=-\int_{[a,b]}f\,dm$. So, the answer is yes, you can flip and introduce a minus sign, but that's just by definition.

Comment: @peek-a-boo is correct. A priori, the notion of the Lebesgue-integral "in opposite direction", i.e. $\displaystyle \int_b^a f$ is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, for $b < a$, we *define* the integral as $$\int_a^b f := -\int_b^a f,$$
where the latter is the usual $$\int_{[a, b]} f \ {\mathrm d}m.$$

However, this is just notational ease for your own convenience; since the statement of the theorem only talks about an integral with limits in the "correct" order, you can actually avoid talking about "incorrect" integrals. Here's the proof for Lebesgue integrals:

By "$f$ is integrable", I assume you mean that $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|\ {\mathrm d}m < \infty$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be arbitrary. By definition of the Lebesgue integral, there exists a simple function $\phi$ such that $0 \le |\phi| \le |f|$ and $$\int_{\mathbb{R}} |f - \phi|\ {\mathrm d}m < \frac\epsilon2.$$

Now, since $\phi$ is simple, we have $M := \displaystyle\sup_{t \in \Bbb R}|\phi(t)| < \infty.$

Define $\delta := \frac{\epsilon}{2M}$. We claim that $|x - y| < \delta \implies |F(x) - F(y)| < \epsilon.$

Let $x, y \in \Bbb R$ be arbitrary such that $|x - y| < \delta$.

Note that since $|F(x) - F(y)| = |F(y) - F(x)|$ and $|x - y| = |y - x|$, we can **assume without loss of generality that $x \ge y$**.

Now, life is simple since we note that $$F(x) - F(y) = \int_x^y f(t) \ {\mathrm d}t.$$
(The integral above is in the "correct" order.)

Now, we easily note that
$$|F(x) - F(y)| \le \int_x^y |f(t)| \ {\mathrm d}t \le \int_x^y |f(t) - \varphi(t)| \ {\mathrm d}t + \int_x^y |\varphi(t)| \ {\mathrm d}t < \frac{\epsilon}{2} + M(x - y).$$
Our choice of $\delta$ gives $M(x - y) < M\delta = \epsilon/2$ and thus, $|F(x) - F(y)| < \epsilon$, as desired.

---

**Addendum:** Let us justify the step that $$F(x) - F(y) = \int_y^x f \ {\mathrm d}m.$$
In general, let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $A, B \in \mathcal{M}$ be such that $A \subset B$.
(In case this is unfamiliar, simply consider the usual Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$ and take $A = (-\infty, y]$ and $B = (-\infty, x]$.)

**Claim.** Let $f \in L^1(\mu)$. Then, $$\int_B f\ {\mathrm d}\mu = \int_{B \setminus A} f\ {\mathrm d}\mu + \int_A f\ {\mathrm d}\mu.$$

*Proof.* We do the usual tricks. The above equality clearly holds when $f$ is an indicator function of some $E \in \mathcal{M}$. (Both sides are precisely $\mu(B \cap E)$. This is including the case that $\mu(B \cap E) = \infty$.)

Thus, by linearity, it is true for all simple functions. By MCT, this extends for all $f \in L^+(\mu)$. Finally, by taking positive and negative parts (and using linearity again), the above is true for all $f \in L^1(\mu)$. $\Box$

In particular, since $f \in L^1(\mu)$, all the integrals are finite. Thus, we may subtract to get
$$\int_B f\ {\mathrm d}\mu - \int_A f\ {\mathrm d}\mu= \int_{B \setminus A} f\ {\mathrm d}\mu.$$

Applied to our case, this shows that
$$F(x) - F(y) = \int_{(y, x]}f\ {\mathrm d}m.$$

As [peek-a-boo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/568204/peek-a-boo) pointed out, since singletons have zero Lebesgue measure, the RHS above is the same as $$\displaystyle\int_{[y, x]}f\ {\mathrm d}m = \int_y^xf\ {\mathrm d}m.$$

Comment: Just a point of confusion, how are the starting integrals in the "correct" order, as we have $F(x) -F(y) = \int_{-\infty}^x f - \int_{-\infty}^y f$? You need to somehow add these, but to do that, you need to flip an integral or do something to add them. I don't see how you avoid this "incorrect" flip. Otherwise, this is precisely the proof I had in mind.

Comment: @VanishingPhilosopher since we assume WLOG $x\geq y$, we have $F(x)-F(y)=\int_{(-\infty,x]}f\,dm-\int_{(-\infty,y]}f\,dm=\int_{(-\infty,x]\setminus (-\infty,y]}f\,dm= \int_{(y,x]}f\,dm\equiv\int_y^xf(t)\,dt$ (where as usual singletons have zero Lebesgue measure, so we can be sloppy with closed/open endpoints). The proof of the second equality (which is the crux of the matter here) can easily be found in any textbook, and follows immediately from the definition of the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @VanishingPhilosopher: That is a good point. peek-a-boo has already outlined a proof. I have added a note for the more general set-up. As a remark, when working with Lebesgue integrals, I find it clearer to think of integrals as integrals over a _set_, instead of an integral "from $a$ to $b$". In fact, I find this perspective nice even for Riemann integrals. It makes things clearer for the case of $\Bbb R^n$.